# How to find a pattern have word and non-word characters after a words combo and before next space using regex

Tags: python, regex

Input text

```
str_ = '''abc xyz pq m_www.google.in_10 -name itel.google.in
abc xyz pq I_www.google.in_9 -name itel.google.com
abc xyz pq I_www.google.in_8 
abc xyz pq I.www_google.com_10 -name itel_google.com_9'''
```

Need to extract the combination coming after 'abc xyz pq ' till next space. This combo can contain \w & dot. Also want to extract combination coming after '-name '. These 2 combination should be a list

Expected output (as a list)

```
'[['m_www.google.in_10', 'itel.google.in']
['I_www.google.in_9', 'itel.google.com']
['I_www.google.in_8', '']
['I_www.google.com_10', 'itel.google.com_9']]'
```

My Pseudo Code

```
import re
re.findall(r'abc xyz pq (\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+) -name? (\w+?)\.(\w+?)\.(\w+?)',str_ )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With specific regex pattern:

```
import re

s = '''abc xyz pq m_www.google.in_10 -name itel.google.in
abc xyz pq I_www.google.in_9 -name itel.google.com
abc xyz pq I_www.google.in_8 
abc xyz pq I.www_google.com_10 -name itel_google.com_9'''

res = list(map(list, re.findall(r'\babc xyz pq (\w+[.\w]+)(?: -name (\w+[.\w]+))?', s)))
pprint(res)
```

The expected output (list of lists):

```
[['m_www.google.in_10', 'itel.google.in'],
 ['I_www.google.in_9', 'itel.google.com'],
 ['I_www.google.in_8', ''],
 ['I.www_google.com_10', 'itel_google.com_9']]
```

---

Regex pattern details:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\w+[.\w]+)` - capture word character(s) `\w+` followed by either `.` char or word character sequence `[.\w]+`
- `(?: ...)` - marks group as non-capturing, though in the above case it contains another captured group (*inner* group)
- `(...)?` - marks group as *optional* (`?` quantifier matches between zero and one times)

Comment: what `(\w+[.\w]+)` will do?

Comment: @sre, see my details

Comment: just one more query if str_ contains `abc xyz pq m_www.google.in_10 yyyy this is unwanted string -name itel.google.in`, how to get the same out

Comment: `\babc xyz pq (\w+[.\w]+).+(?: -name (\w+[.\w]+))?', s)`, it has to work right

Comment: @sre, `r'\babc xyz pq (\w+[.\w]+)(?:.*? -name (\w+[.\w]+))?'` - should be better

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex in `re.findall`:

```
>>> for i in re.findall(r'abc xyz pq\s+([\w.]+)(?:\s+-name\s+([\w.]+))?', str_):
...     print (i)
...
('m_www.google.in_10', 'itel.google.in')
('I_www.google.in_9', 'itel.google.com')
('I_www.google.in_8', '')
('I.www_google.com_10', 'itel_google.com_9')
```

Note that the list doesn't match your expected data structure but you can iterate this list and create your custom structure.

Alternatively you may use `re.finditer` and prepare your custom list.

Comment: What is `([\w.]+)` will do

Comment: `[\w]+` matches 1 or more word or dot characters,

Comment: just one more query if str_ contains abc xyz pq m_www.google.in_10 yyyy this is unwanted string -name itel.google.in, how to get the same out

Comment: Sorry I stepped out for some work But solution is pretty simple Just throw a `.*` before `\s+` so make it: `r'abc xyz pq\s+([\w.]+)(?:*\s+-name\s+([\w.]+))?'`

Comment: Thank you so much. Great help. One dot should be added in second part after ?:

Comment: Yes that a typo :)